# Affix issue on responsive site with grids

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two columns in my grid. A `col-md-3` which has a `list-group` and `col-md-9` with my page content. I would like the `list-group` to follow while scrolling and this is where `affix` does the trick.

Unfortunately the affix messes up the width of my responsive grid columns. Is there no other way to fix this issue but to hack myself through by using the event fires from the affix library?

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/5jywokfL/

As you can see the width is offcourse altered due to the `postion:fixed` as according to the bootstrap documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

But how do i make a workaround to this problem while still maintaining the responsiveness of the site? In mobile platforms except larger screens as on tablets the affix would be disabled entirely and the page would only rely on the responsiveness of the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Bootstrap's site, .affix is static until the breakpoint you want to use it, then you make it fixed. You also make the width of the affixed element in the media queries. Since there's no border around their side nav, you don't notice it, but you do with stuff that has borders or backgrounds.

There is no "problem" with the affixed plugin. Position:fixed needs a width in this situation.

My solution use jQuery to get the width along with the CSS, but not widths on the affixed, and set it up as follows:

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/rucoti/2/

**jQuery**

```
/*! Copyright 2012, Ben Lin (http://dreamerslab.com/)
 * Licensed under the MIT License (LICENSE.txt).
 *
 * Version: 1.0.16
 *
 * Requires: jQuery >= 1.2.3
 */
(function(a){a.fn.addBack=a.fn.addBack||a.fn.andSelf;
a.fn.extend({actual:function(b,l){if(!this[b]){throw'$.actual => The jQuery method "'+b+'" you called does not exist';}var f={absolute:false,clone:false,includeMargin:false};
var i=a.extend(f,l);var e=this.eq(0);var h,j;if(i.clone===true){h=function(){var m="position: absolute !important; top: -1000 !important; ";e=e.clone().attr("style",m).appendTo("body");
};j=function(){e.remove();};}else{var g=[];var d="";var c;h=function(){c=e.parents().addBack().filter(":hidden");d+="visibility: hidden !important; display: block !important; ";
if(i.absolute===true){d+="position: absolute !important; ";}c.each(function(){var m=a(this);var n=m.attr("style");g.push(n);m.attr("style",n?n+";"+d:d);
});};j=function(){c.each(function(m){var o=a(this);var n=g[m];if(n===undefined){o.removeAttr("style");}else{o.attr("style",n);}});};}h();var k=/(outer)/.test(b)?e[b](i.includeMargin):e[b]();
j();return k;}});})(jQuery);


 $(window).on('load resize', function() {

    var colwidth = $('.col-sm-3').actual('width');

   $('.list-group-item').css('width', (colwidth) + 'px');

   
   
 });
```

**CSS**

```
.affix.list-group {
    position: static
}
@media (max-width:767px) { 
    .affix.list-group {
        width: auto!important
    }
}
@media (min-width:768px) { 
    .affix.list-group {
        position: fixed
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="list-group" data-spy="affix">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">An item</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            Add a lot of text here so that you produce a scroll. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Everything works, but i noticed that when the page is squeezed together it does not go back to its responsive state, where the `list-group` is on the top, but it remains on the side..

Comment: You had col-xs in your markup. If you use the col-sm it works as expected: http://jsbin.com/rucoti/2

Comment: Notice that the jQuery changed too.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jywokfL/1/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 hidden-xs">
            <div class="list-group" style="margin-top:50px" data-spy="affix">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">An item</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
            Lorem ipsum.......
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The first column is still malformed size, its smaller than it should be in width.. I think its a affix problem with `position:fixed`?